# Why node js server throws 502 while processing a large mysql data set

Tags: mysql, node.js, http, relational-database, scaling

I have been working with an express application with a large mysql data set. I'm joining a table that contains 800 000 rows with two other tables. The query look something like this

```
select a.*,b.name,c.code
from table_1 as a
inner join table_2 as b
on b.project=a.id
inner join table_3 as c 
on c.id=a.c_id
```

When I run this query on mysql client I'm getting the response within 1000 ms. However when I call the query from application when loading the page, the page loads for couple of seconds and throws 502 error.

I tried to reduce the size of database rows and then it worked. But in real time I don't want this to happen.How can I prevent the 502 error even if the table has hundreds of thousands of rows and is there any way to optimize my query further?.

I'm using "MySQL" npm package.My node version is 4.5 and express version is 4.4

Comment: It could be your query times out or your process dies because it uses too much memory. Does adding `LIMIT 25000` fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks Tadman .In this case I used a count to count the number of rows and did limit . I am concerned about the future because  few tables get a high volume of data daily .what can be done for better scaling apart from optimizing queries? . Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: If you have an unbounded number of results then the time it takes your query to run will likewise be unbounded. Many APIs have some kind of generous limit to prevent things running forever, often termed "pagination", where an API will only return X thousand or X million results at a time and you'll need to make an additional request for more.